# My question was wrongfully closed, IMO. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question in SO that was closed as "not being a real question" when, IMO, it really is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880063/would-visual-studio-ever-have-good-support-for-javascript-or-is-it-impossible

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bringing it up here is the right thing to do

As for your question, you kind of have two questions mixed together:

- Will Visual Studio ever have good support for javascript?
- Is it possible for IDEs to be able to fully support dynamic languages?

The former requires people to know the future and isn't particularly good. The latter would be better on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but is on-topic on SO. You need to get rid of all the stuff like "Will VS ever", "an argument i had with a friend", "working with it is a pain"; all of that is irrelevant and makes the question seem worse than it is

Comment: Agreed.  If you get rid of all the argumentative bits, there might be the kernel of a good question in there.

Comment: i edited and voted for reopen. thanks.

Comment: so basically all i can do is just vote for reopen and that's it? even though it is a real question?

Comment: @Elad And wait for other people to reopen, yes. The question has 3 reopen votes so far

Comment: @Elad: I see your question. I still don't think it is sufficient because of the editorial commentary. Just leave it as "will IDEs like VS ever be able to fully support dynamic languages like javascript and allow full intelisense like is possible with C# and any other static languages?" - the question is too chatty.

Comment: @BrAvada - noted.

Comment: @Elad: No, "Will Visual Studio ever have good support for javascript?" is not the good part of the question.  That's asking us to predict the future.  "Is it possible for IDEs to be able to fully support dynamic languages?" is the good part.

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, that should have been closed as "not constructive".

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Rule of thumb, if your question starts with "an argument i had with a friend;" it's probably not a good fit here.

Comment: then remove the "an argument" thing. the question is a real question, with real ways of proving it. it's REALLY not ment to solicit debate - i have a question i'm not sure i can answer and that's where i'm asking for help.

Comment: @Elad: You're able to edit your own question, even when it's closed.  Don't rely on me to do it for you.  The words "an argument" aren't the problem, the actual argument is.

Answer (score 2):

I think that https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask your question. In general, Stack Overflow is for posting specific code-related questions, not "Would tool X ever do Y?"

That being said, [the Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) is a bit ambiguous about this (emphasis mine).

> **Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are
>   interested in conceptual questions on software development.**
>
> This can include topics such as:
>
> - Software engineering
> - Developer testing
> - Algorithm and data structure concepts
> - Design patterns
> - Architecture
> - Development methodologies
> - Quality assurance
> - Software law
> - Freelancing and business concerns
>
> **If your question is about programming tools, please ask on Stack
>   Overflow instead.**

I imagine that there's an element of subjectivity involved, but in general, I would avoid overly broad or potentially argumentative questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i understand, but there's nothing argumentative in my question. it might have been more proper to ask it in 'programmers' and i'll remember that for next time, but that should not warrant closing a question IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, I paused for a moment when I typed "argumentative" myself, but I think that [Michael explained this best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/my-question-was-wrongfully-closed-imho-what-to-do/100339#100339) by saying that one of your questions "requires people to know the future and isn't particularly good" and could thus become argumentative: it's really just conjecture based on reasonable guesses.

Comment: Programmers is bit ambiguous about everything.

Answer (score -9):

Your only solution is to find a site with more open-minded mods. SO and stack exchange people are very strict about the arbitrary rules they set up to decide what can and cannot be asked here, and there is no discussion.

Comment: You can't say it doesn't work though. SO provides me with faster and better answers than any other site I've found yet.

Comment: Yeah, the site is great, shame the mods aren't :)

Comment: By the way, the people downvoting me are pretty much proving my point :-D

Comment: Did you not participate in the mod election? I was rather satisfied that my candidate was elected.

Comment: -1 I completely disagree with you.  I *am not a mod* and I feel that the problem with his question is that it was poorly formed.  Working with him to improve it, I believe there is a portion of it which can be asked on SO.  The discussion part on what will happen really doesn't fit on *any* Q&A site -- more likely a blog soliciting comments.  And FYI -- votes on Meta mean [something very different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: You're not a mod, but you're the same kind of person :) I know very well votes on meta mean disagreement, and this is exactly my point: everyone disagrees with me, yet every other answers goes to great lenght to show that the OP is not welcome here.

Comment: If there was really "no discussion" and the OP was "not welcome here", the mods would have just deleted this Meta question so that no-one could respond to it.

Comment: I don't call that a "discussion", but whatever. I'm still essentially right: OP's only hope for his question is to find another site.

Comment: Your view as expressed here amounts to the "No true Scotsman" fallacy, or simple conspiracy theory -- anyone who disagrees with you is "one of them": «You're not a mod, but you're the same kind of person»

Comment: @Josh : nope, I base my assertion on facts: Mr Tibbits has over 3000 meta karma, he's exactly the kind of nolife SO drone that I'm talking about.