# Should this question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, off-topic

(Inspired by *the right thing to do* comment  on [My question was wrongfully closed, IMO. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/my-question-was-wrongfully-closed-imho-what-to-do/100339#100339))

This question looks worth re-opening it or at least somehow else removing an *off-topic* stamp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689543/changing-the-native-language.

As of now, the question (not mine if that matters) is denoted as off-topic. The reason why I doubt this decision is provided in the question's comments.

Comment: There's an answer in the comments.  Do we really need to reopen it?

Comment: hm. If you ask what exactly bothers me: it's not the _closed_ status per se but the _off topic_ stamp written in big fat letters. I'd be comfortable with any change that would wipe out that stamp - if that happens then I won't have issues be it open or closed

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @Hans-Passant thanks for pointing that out I added comment that hopefully clarifies that this is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read it, it's not a question about developing or about a tool that is used by developers; it's asking about a tool that would change the native language for a device running Java mobile.

As per removing the part that says the question has been closed as off-topic, that is only possible if the question is re-opened. Closed questions always report the reason they have been closed, and it is not possible to remove that from single closed questions.
Removing the part that explains why the question was closed seems contrary to what I would expect. How could users vote to re-open the question, if they don't see the reason why the question has been closed?

Comment: well to start with the question is quite fuzzy. However, your reading looks slippery to me. OP asks about _jar file_ - this in my view doesn't match your reading: _"tool that would change the native language for a device running Java mobile"_. Jar file corresponds to API (eg `jsr238.jar`) that programmer can use - at least this is the way I've seen inexperienced programmers use it at forums (myself I'd never use words _jar file_ that way). Wrt _closing / removal of the off-topic part_ - your point makes good sense to me.

Comment: note I am going to be offline next few weeks => won't be able to further maintain this discussion sorry

Comment: The question uses the phrase "or package software which changes the native language of Java mobile to." The native language is normally set in a device, or a computer; for example, if I ask about a tool that allows me to change the native language used by the Mac OS X, the tool is acting on the settings of a computer running Mac OS X. That is why I get the user is talking of how to set the native language on a device running Java Mobile. It could be I am wrong, but the question make me think that is what is asked.

Comment: per my past experience at _java-me_ forums I'd say that in this case you seem to be indeed wrong